# Tried to change resolution in Ubuntu 20.04, seems like it worked but it did not

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I tried to custom change the resolution for my new screen to 2560x1080. Used xrandr commands. As a result I see it in the list of available resolutions in the display management menu, but clicking on it doesn't bring any effect. It is same old 1920x1080. No clue what to do now, since changing things with xrandr seems to be the only option around also doesn't throw an error. Any advice would be appreciated[as you can see, 2560x1080 is in the list, but has not effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWtqC.png).

Comment: What make/model display do you have?  What is the native resolution of the display?

Comment: What (exactly) are the xrandr commands you used? What is the make/model of monitor? What is the make/model of graphics device? How is the PC connected to the monitor? And also I suggest you update your question with the results of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and `xrandr`

Comment: @Nmath It is LG 29WN600-W, the native resolution is 2560x1080.

Comment: @codlord I used: cvt 2560 1080 60 then sudo xrandr --newmode <modename etc> then sudo xrandr --addmode and finally $ xrandr --output <customModename>. The PC is connected via HDMI. the Graphic card is intel's that comes with 10th generation i5